# Call User.Identity.GetUserId() from Helpers with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-helpers

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC,

I moved an HTTP POST method from my controller to Helpers, and I can't call `User.Identity.GetUserId()` from `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` library.

Why can I not use this library from the helpers? Thanks

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `User` object that you get from within the controller using `User.Identity.GetUserId()` is of type `HttpContext.User`.

You can get get the current `HttpContext` by using `HttpContext.Current` which sits within `System.Web`.

You'll need the using statement for the Extension method too.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Web;

public class MyClass()
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // Get the current context
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        // Get the user id
        var userId = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
}
```

I personally would recommend passing this value in as a parameter from your controller if you're retrieving it within your helper methods because it makes it a bit more clear that it relies on it?

You will need to get this value from your controller and pass it as a parameter if you move the helper method into your service layer etc.

Comment: Thanks mate, I knew I wasn't calling from the right thing. I'll follow your advise. Thanks again